# Calculate SD's (svysd) of Quartiles in once with weighted data using survey package

Tags: r, standards, survey, standard-deviation

I would like to calculate the SDs of Quartiles in one code using a weighted analysis with the survey package.

With the means of the Quartiles it works like this:

```
svyby(~ x, by = ~as.factor(var_in_quartiles), design = weights, FUN = svymean)
```

With output:

```
  as.factor(WAISTquart)     x        se
1                     1 1.467615 0.05541616
2                     2 1.389899 0.06070003
3                     3 1.294789 0.04032355
4                     4 1.156874 0.02414524
```

If I try this with svysd to get SDs i get the error:

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Anyone know a solution? Or just recalulate the SDs with the given SEs?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: Never mind I already found the answer and its really easy, just add all the variables you want to konw the SDs from with '+' sign! see: https://rdrr.io/cran/jtools/man/svysd.html